# Google Calendar - Apps Script to Add Attachment from Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Can anyone help? I'm a bit lost here... How can I alter this code to add attachments from my google drive? Please help a total noob...

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var nameSource = ss.getSheetByName("Template");  
var newDate = nameSource.getRange('F1');
var newDate2= newDate.getValues();  
var date_of_event = ss.getRange('F1').getValue();
var date = newDate2;
var event_title = ss.getRange('B14').getValue();
var dSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');  
var description = dSheet.getRange('A21').getValues();
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('myemail@gmail.com');

 //Insert PDF

var fileId = DriveApp.getFilesByName(newDate2);  

cal.createAllDayEvent('Apply Chem', date_of_event , {supportAttachments: true}).setDescription(description);

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Apologies but I prefer to just provide you a few guidelines rather than to help you alter the code.

As mentioned in [Add Drive attachments to events](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/create-events?utm_campaign=calendarAPI-615&utm_source=gadbc&utm_medium=blog#attachments), there are two parts of attaching a Google Drive file to a Calendar event:

> 1. Get the file `alternateLink` URL, `title`, and `mimeType` from the [Drive API Files resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files), typically with the `files.get()` method.
> 2. Create or update an event with the `attachments` fields set in the request body and the `supportsAttachments` parameter set to `true`.

However, please note that **you must perform a full sync of all events** before enabling the `supportsAttachments` parameter for event modifications when adding attachments support into your existing app that stores events locally.

Code samples demonstrating how to update an existing event to add an attachment can be found in the documentation.